# Using SFTP with Thunar file manager and a PEM key on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thunar

I am using the Thunar file manager on Ubuntu Desktop and wish to connect to a Ubuntu server using SFTP and a PEM key.

What is the syntax in Thunar for this? Was thinking along the lines of

```
sftp://user@myserver.com /pemkey ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Added the following to my ssh config file:

```
Host myserver
HostName xx.xx.xx.xx
User myuser
IdentityFile key.pem
Compression yes
```

then sftp://myserver in Thunar.

Now have a connection.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement [user10311596's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699350), you have to add this settings in: `~/.ssh/config` file. Create one if the file does not exists.